# How to link fftw3 libraries for c++ in vs code in ubuntu?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, fftw

I downloaded the fftw3 tar file and unzipped it and configured it and did the make and make install in ~/usr/include/

now I wrote a simple code

```
#include<iostream>
#include <fftw3.h>
int main()
{
    fftw_complex *T=(fftw_complex *)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*5*5);
    return 0;
}
```

Then I went to the c_cpp_properties.json file for vs code and updated it

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Mac",
        "includePath": [
            "/usr/include",
            "/usr/local/include",
            "${workspaceRoot}"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "/usr/include",
                "/usr/local/include",
                "${workspaceRoot}"
            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
            "databaseFilename": ""
        },
        "macFrameworkPath": [
            "/System/Library/Frameworks",
            "/Library/Frameworks"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Linux",
        "includePath": [
            "/usr/include/c++/5",
            "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5",
            "/usr/include/c++/5/backward",
            "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include",
            "/usr/local/include",
            "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed",
            "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu",
            "/usr/include",
            "~/usr/include/",
            "${workspaceRoot}"
        ],
        "defines": ["_DEBUG"],
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "/usr/include/c++/5",
                "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5",
                "/usr/include/c++/5/backward",
                "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include",
                "/usr/local/include",
                "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed",
                "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu",
                "/usr/include",
                "~/usr/include/",
                "${workspaceRoot}"
            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
            "databaseFilename": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/include",
            "${workspaceRoot}"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/include/*",
                "${workspaceRoot}"
            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
            "databaseFilename": ""
        }
    }
],
"version": 3
```

}

you can see that I added the links to ~/usr/include
in the includepath section

now, it still shows the error

```
/tmp/ccBhp7Pq.o: In function `main':
Source1.cpp:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `fftw_malloc'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

not sure what to do now.
running in ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Add the fftw library and path, add `-lfftw3` and `-L"~/usr/lib` to the "args" of your build task in the `tasks.json`

Answer (score 1):

The [Building your code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp#_building-your-code) section of the Microsoft C/C++ VS Code extension says that if you want to build your application you have to add all your required arguments to the build task's "args" in the `"tasks.json"`.

So just add the *fftw* library name and path to the arguments like:

```
...
 "tasks": [
        ...
        "args": [
            ...
            "-lfftw3", "-L~/usr/lib"
        ]
]
...
```