# How to compile graphics program on ubuntu by adding -lgraph flag to the compilation command to Vscode code runner?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, graphics, sdl

I am using ubuntu 16.04. I have followed the steps to use **SDL graphics** in ubuntu as mentioned in
https://askubuntu.com/questions/525051/how-do-i-use-graphics-h-in-ubuntu.
I am able to succesfully compile and run a graphics program manually using gedit and the terminal by adding `-lgraph` to the compilation command. On internet I found that we can add this compiler setting in codeblocks which says:

> Graphics.h library is actually deprecated.
>
> You need to compile it with -lgraph flag to compiler
>
> g++ demo.cpp -o demo -lgraph
>
> If in codeblocks, you need to add this to settings
>
> Settings -> Compiler Linker settings In the "Other linker options" add
>   -lgraph and press ok.
>
> Now it should compile!

Is there a way to do this on **Vscode**?

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49486880/how-to-link-fftw3-libraries-for-c-in-vs-code-in-ubuntu/49488705#49488705

Comment: @bruno can you just post the above comment as an answer, so that I can mark it as solved?

Comment: sorry but it is a duplicated question, and because I already put it as duplicate (to an other question, but wrongly) and I retract my vote I cannot vote to close it again (until you edit it)